# Как закрепить систему координат для объекта в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, координаты, move

Пока только знакомлюсь с функционалом Unity и вот столкнулся с проблемой:

Если 3D объект переворачивается на бок - его система координат тоже переворачивается и кнопка, отвечающая за движение вправо(к примеру), начинает двигать объект в пол.

Возможно как то закрепить положение только для системы координат?

Если нужно - вот код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Controls : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private GameObject obj;
public float speed = 1f;
public float JumpForce = 3f;
private bool IsGrounded;
private void Start()
{
    Transform transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
private void OnCollisionEnter()
{
    IsGrounded = true;
}
private void Update()
{
    // Движение
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        obj.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        obj.transform.Translate(Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        obj.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        obj.transform.Translate(Vector3.back * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    
    //Прыжок
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsGrounded)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(new Vector3(0, JumpForce, 0), 
obj.transform.position, ForceMode.Impulse);
        IsGrounded=false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. У компонента `Rigidbody` в инспекторе выставьте галочки напротив `Freeze rotation`.
2. Не используйте сразу несколько видов перемещения, если перемещаете объект с помощью `Rigidbody`, то перемещайте только таким образом, иначе могут возникать разные курьёзные ситуации.

Comment: Я не хочу отключать вращение объекта, я хочу именно зафиксировать его систему координат.
Если сделать как вы говорите - объект, на 3/4 свисающий с выступа, не будет падать - а такое мне не подходит.

Comment: Я написал два совета, если не подошел один, значит подойдет второй. Используйте метод `MovePosition` у компонента `Rigidbody` вместо `transform.Translate`

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте галочку в скрипте Rigidbody на поле Freeze Rotarion на x и z.
Компонент Transform не нужно кэшировать в методе Start.